# How to change img src with HTML5 and Javascript using radio button

Tags: javascript, image

I am doing an assignment in which a web page displays the flag of a country based on what radio button is selected. The goal of the assignment is to use Javascript to change the src attribute of an img element. I do not believe we are supposed to use functions since those are not covered until the next chapter. I have followed all the guides in the current chapter but they only discuss changing text, not images.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Flags</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="CountryList" method="get">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="radio" name="country" onclick="document.ProductImage.src='argentina.jpg'" />Argentina
                        <br />
                        <input type="radio" name="country" onclick="document.ProductImage.src='australia.jpg'" />Australia
                        <br />
                        <input type="radio" name="country" onclick="document.ProductImage.src='bolivia.jpg'" />Bolivia
                        <br />
                        <input type="radio" name="country" onclick="document.ProductImage.src='cuba.jpg'" />Cuba
                        <br />
                        <input type="radio" name="country" onclick="document.ProductImage.src='finland.jpg'" />Finland
                        <br />
                        <input type="radio" name="country" onclick="document.ProductImage.src='france.jpg'" />France
                        <br />
                        <input type="radio" name="country" onclick="document.ProductImage.src='italy.jpg'" />Italy
                        <br />
                        <input type="radio" name="country" onclick="document.ProductImage.src='peru.jpg'" />Peru
                        <br />
                        <input type="radio" name="country" onclick="document.ProductImage.src='syria.jpg'" />Syria
                        <br />
                        <input type="radio" name="country" onclick="document.ProductImage.src='tunisia.jpg'" />Tunisia
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a><img id="ProductImage" src="" alt="Flag" /></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Could anybody point me in the right direction or let me know if it is impossible to change the img src attribute without functions?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget to select your answer once you found one.

Answer (score 1):

If you plan on doing it all inline like that, change

```
document.ProductImage.src
```

to

```
document.getElementById('ProductImage').src
```

And all will be well.

You really should be calling a function to keep your code in one place (what if the ID of the image changes?) though.

Comment: About using a function instead of inline code; my first thought as well. But then I read his question again: 
> I do not believe we are supposed to use functions since those are not covered until the next chapter.

Comment: Yeah, I read that as well, and why I posted (along with you) the inline answer... but it still pains me to see the inlines =)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
document.getElementById('ProductImage').src='bolivia.jpg'
```

and so on...

Comment: Thanks some of my searches referenced

    getElementById

But there was never any discussion in the book or in class on why to use that, we were told to just used document.ProductImage.src.

Answer (score 0):

You're not really selecting the image properly, use `document.getElementById("ProductImage").src = ...`, though I'd really recommend using a function, inline handlers are obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, and it [appears that I'm not](http://jsbin.com/ugameb/1/edit), `document.ProductImage` refers to an `img` tag with the `name` attribute set to `ProductImage`. If you're referencing elements by ID, use `document.getElementById()` instead.

Your fix:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Flags</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="CountryList" method="get">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="radio" name="country" onclick="updateProductImage('argentina.jpg')" />Argentina
                        <br />
                        <input type="radio" name="country" onclick="updateProductImage('australia.jpg')" />Australia
                        <br />
                        <input type="radio" name="country" onclick="updateProductImage('bolivia.jpg')" />Bolivia
                        <br />
                        <input type="radio" name="country" onclick="updateProductImage('cuba.jpg')" />Cuba
                        <br />
                        <input type="radio" name="country" onclick="updateProductImage('finland.jpg')" />Finland
                        <br />
                        <input type="radio" name="country" onclick="updateProductImage('france.jpg')" />France
                        <br />
                        <input type="radio" name="country" onclick="updateProductImage('italy.jpg')" />Italy
                        <br />
                        <input type="radio" name="country" onclick="updateProductImage('peru.jpg')" />Peru
                        <br />
                        <input type="radio" name="country" onclick="updateProductImage('syria.jpg')" />Syria
                        <br />
                        <input type="radio" name="country" onclick="updateProductImage('tunisia.jpg')" />Tunisia
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a><img id="ProductImage" name="ProductImage" src="" alt="Flag" /></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
        <script>
            function updateProductImage(src) {
                document.ProductImage.src = src || 'no-image.jpg'; // Set image source to given source or no image of no source specified.
                // Or use document.getElementById("ProductImage").src instead.
                return true; // Continue with the click event.
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

As a bonus; a working example of the code above:
http://jsbin.com/ihimay/1/edit

> I do not believe we are supposed to use functions since those are not covered until the next chapter.

I figured you could score some bonus points by producing clean code instead of messy inline javascript. If it's really not an option to use functions, simply replace `updateProductImage('argentina.jpg')` with `document.ProductImage.src = 'argentina.jpg' || 'no-image.jpg'`

Answer (score 0):

Change `<img id` to `<img name` and it appears to work in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I want to change product image in my Magento Store on radio Button Click without using any extension.

I just want to change its color into Sepia and B/w in to same image container on radio button click. (http://demo.lifestylewallart.com.au/)

As there will be number of images in my magento so code should be minimum.

I tried it using html and css on simple file.

Please have a look and let me know how we can use this in better way in magento store.

```css
img { display: block; width: 50%; }
    
    .sepia {
    -webkit-filter: sepia(1);
    filter: sepia(1);
    }
    
    .gray {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
    filter: grayscale(1);
    }
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
    Original : - <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE5lz.png"><br>
    <div class="sepia">
    Sepia : - <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE5lz.png">
    </div>
    <div class="gray">
    Gray :- <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE5lz.png">
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```